# Interacting with third-party android application

Tags: android

I wish to develop an Android app, that will send an auto-reply message whenever I get a message in my favorite app i.e Whatsapp, Facebook Messenger, etc.

My question is, how do I interact with other applications on my device, so I can read and write the data on them?

For those who commented that it is not possible...
LastPass is a user/password vault application and somehow it identifies applications login screens and injects the details into the text fields... any idea how they do that?

Comment: Generally, you don't, unless the app developers offer some sort of API for doing this.

Comment: Along with previous comment - look at `BroadcastReceiver` class and check for push notifications from your apps... You might be able to read the notification, but sending back data requires that Intent to be exposed

Comment: LastPass is a user/password safe application and somehow it identifies applications login screens and injects the details into the text fields... any idea how they do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use API for interacting with 3rd party applications.
Here is an example of WhatsApp.
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

There are two ways to integrate with WhatsApp:

- Through a custom URL scheme
- Through Android's intent system.

I don't think 3rd party application will provide you the functionalities which you need.